# Error occurred prerendering page "/". TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: next.js, fetch, vercel, sanity, pre-rendering

I am getting this error on command screen while running 'npm run build' but 'npm run dev' is running fine and because of this I am not able to deploy this project. I am using nextJS 13

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async fetchPageInfo (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1121:17)
    at async getStaticProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1041:22)
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
- info Generating static pages (3/3)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Here is my source code link
[Github](https://github.com/Devansh-DJ007/portfolio-react-1.0)

I am stuck on it for days. Please help

I have tried a lot of things and nothing is working till now

Comment: The error is likely occurring in the fetchPageInfo function within your /pages/index.js file. Double check the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.